# Can not create pivot table by VBA but I can manually create pivot table from same data source

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

```
    Sub CreatePivot()
      Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
      Dim PTCache As PivotCache
      Dim PT As PivotTable
      Dim PTRange As Range
      Dim FinalRow As Long
      Dim FinalCol As Long
    
       Set NewSheet = Workbooks("東京威力_樞紐分 
       析.xlsm").Sheets.Add(Before:=Workbooks("東京威力_樞紐分 
        析.xlsm").Worksheets(1))
       NewSheet.Name = "Summary"
        
       For Each PT In NewSheet.PivotTables
         PT.TableRange2.Clear
       Next PT
        
       Set PTRange = getTable("Table1").Range
    
      'Create PivotCaches
       Set PTCache = Workbooks("東京威力_樞紐分
       析.xlsm").PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, 
       SourceData:=PTRange.Address)
        
    
      'Create PivotTable
       Set PT = 
       PTCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=NewSheet.Cells(2, 
       2),tableName:="PivotTable1")
        
       'ManualUpdate On
       PT.ManualUpdate = True
    
       PT.AddFields RowFields:=Array("Recharge BU", "Main Category"), 
       ColumnFields:="Recharge To"
    
       With PT.PivotFields("Hours")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlSum
        .Position = 1
        .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
        .Name = "Total - Hours"
       End With
    
      'Calcu PivotTable
      PT.ManualUpdate = False
      PT.ManualUpdate = True

    End Sub
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Function getTable(tableName As String) As ListObject
        Dim FinalRow As Long
    
        With Workbooks("東京威力_樞紐分析.xlsm").Worksheets("原始資料")
          On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
            FinalRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
            Set getTable = .ListObjects(tableName)
        End With
     Exit Function
     
     ErrorHandler:
        Debug.Print Err.Number; ":" & Err.Description
     
        If getTable Is Nothing Then
        Workbooks("東京威力_樞紐分析.xlsm").Worksheets("原始資料").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, 
        Workbooks("東京威力_樞紐分析.xlsm").Worksheets("原始資料").Range("A1:AK" & FinalRow), , xlYes).Name = "Table1"

        Set getTable = Worksheets("原始資料").ListObjects(tableName)
     End If
     Resume Next

    End Function
```

---

Hi Folks, the Purpose of the code is to create pivot table.
But I Got Error Message
『The PivotTable field name is not valid. To create a PivotTable report, you must use data that is organized as a list with labeled columns. If you are changing the name of a PivotTable field, you must type a new name for the field』 when I created Pivot Table.  (at the line==> PTCache.CreatePivotTable)

What could possibly go wrong ? Thanks

PS : I can manually create pivot table from  same data source.

Comment: I would cheat by recording a macro for creating a PT in your scenario then refer to that code.

Comment: I found that the code is modified as follows " 『Set PTCache = Workbooks("東京威力_樞紐分析.xlsm").PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Table1")』, then it works. But I still don't understand what's wrong with my previous code.

Comment: Got it... answer logged below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SourceData:=`PTRange.Address` will give us the cell address without the sheet name, e.g. `$C$7:$G$17`. This do not work for PT.

`SourceData` requires range reference with sheet name, e.g.

[image]

Therefore, it should be
`SourceData:= PTRange.Parent.Name & "!" & PTRange.Address`. But if your sheet name contain spaces, then it should be `SourceData:= "'" & PTRange.Parent.Name & "'!" & PTRange.Address`.

Since your data is contained in named-range `Table1`, using the name as the `SourceData` will be much much easier.

[image]